# How can I, using PL/SQL, remove punctuation embedded in numbers?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am writing a function to clean up addresses in PL/SQL and want to remove "/-." from the middle of numbers. I suspect that should be easy with a regexp_replace. Unfortunately I still haven't wrapped my head around regular expressions well enough.

So my input might look like "123-4 Cherry Lane" and I would like it to look like "123 4 Cherry Lane" But I would like "123 Blake-Habersham" to look like "123 Blake-Habersham", no difference.

Since I would like to learn from this not just copy and paste code, I would like to understand the answer as well.

In pseudo code I want to replace all '[any characters][1-9] for any length followed by a separator and [0-9] followed by [any characters]' with '[any characters][1-9] for any length followed [any characters]'

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace('123-4 Cherry-Lane 123- -123', '(\d+)\D(\d+)', '\1 \2') from dual;
```

[at least one digit][not a digit][at least one digit] -> [at least one digit]["space"][at least one digit]

if you know exactly which "not a digit" you want to replace you can use (for example) "[-.,@%&]" instead of "\D".

Or you can use Oracle special functions:

```
regexp_replace('123-4 Cherry-Lane 123- -123', '([[:digit:]]+)[[:punct:]]([[:digit:]]+)', '\1 \2')
```